# Configure grunt-sass to break CSS if error in Sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs

I have grunt-sass set up in my project, it works great, the only thing I'd like it to do is to break your CSS if you make a mistake in your Sass. Presently all it does is throw an error in terminal like this:

```
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning: /www/_assets/scss/modules/_header.scss:3: error: unbound variable $gray
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The CSS will remain unchanged and so you may not notice straight away in your browser. Does anybody know a way that you can make it behave more like Compass, where it will replace your CSS with a message saying that compilation has failed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using `grunt-contrib-compass`? Just curious...

Comment: Yes, grunt-sass uses the node-sass compiler which is much faster than compass or the native sass compiler https://github.com/andrew/node-sass